# prevent multiple http request send by using fetch

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, dom, fetch

I'm creating a chrome extension, in which I take input from using prompt and send it to the server using an HTTP request. By doing this I'm facing duplication of data, which means the extension is sending multiple requests to the server, which I want to prevent. (Note: by taking data from prompt only once it is sending multiple requests of same data)

Example code:
Front-End:

```
var data = prompt("Enter your data here");
if (data !== null || data !== ''){
fetch('http://localhost:3000/post', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    data: data
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}).then((res) => {
  console.log("wait for whole req");
  return res.json();
}).then((resData) => {
  console.log(resData);
  console.log("req send successfully");
  // note = null;
}).catch((error) => {
  // note = null;
  console.log(error.message);
  // alert(error.message);
});
```

Back-End:

```
app.post("/post", function(req, res) {
    const data = req.body.data;
    dataList.push(data);
    res.status(200).json({
       status: "uploaded"
    });
});
```

Here, data is one array that stores data taken from the user.

Comment: What is the cause for multiple requests? user input?

Comment: yes user input can be that issue, Maybe it is creating multiple threads. I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can limit concurrent requests by a flag

```
var data = null, 
isLoading = false, // perhaps you need to make this persistent depending on your overall architecture
if (!isLoading) 
{
   data = prompt("Enter your data here");
}
if (data !== null || data !== ''){
isLoading = true;
fetch('http://localhost:3000/post', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    data: data
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  }
}).then((res) => {
  console.log("wait for whole req");
  
  return res.json();
}).then((resData) => {
  console.log(resData);
  console.log("req send successfully");
  isLoading = false
  // note = null;
}).catch((error) => {
  // note = null;
  console.log(error.message);
  isLoading = false
  // alert(error.message);
});
```